# implement copy function using fscanf and fprintf

Tags: c

1. implement a copy function that uses `fscanf` to read one character at a time from the input, and `fprintf` to print one character at a time to the output.
2. implement a copy function that uses `fgetc` to read one character at a time from the input, and `fputc` to print one character at a time to the output.

Is there any other ways that I could do it without using `c[BUFSIZ]`?

Below is what I've tried to code:

First question:

```
static void copy(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
    char c = 0;
    while (fscanf(input, "%c", &c) != 0) {
        fprintf(output, "%c", c);   
    }
}
```

Second question:

```
static void copy(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
    char c[BUFSIZ];
    while (fgets(c, BUFSIZ, input) != NULL) {
        fputs(c, output);
    }
}
```

It is expected to do the copy function and detail is mentioned above

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `fgetc` and `fputc` for your second problem?

Comment: "without using `c[BUFSIZ]`" ... yes - it says "one character at a time". No array is needed. Please read the fgetc(3) and fputc(3) man pages where you will find there is no `char` type.

Comment: I'm confused about how could I do this without an array

Comment: `int inp = fgetc(input); fputc(inp, output);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems in both answers:

- in the first code, you test if `fscanf()` returns non zero. You should instead test if it returns `1`, indicating a character was successfully read. Indeed at the end of the file `fscanf()` will return `EOF`, which is also non zero.
- in the second code, you should use `fgetc()` and `fputc()`, not `fgets()` and `fputs()`. A single `int c;` is required for this approach.

Here are corrected versions:

First question:

```
static void copy(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
    char c;
    while (fscanf(input, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        fprintf(output, "%c", c);   
    }
}
```

Second question:

```
static void copy(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        fputc(c, output);
    }
}
```

Note how `c` must be defined as `char` for the `fscanf()` version and `int` for the `fgetc()` approach. `fgetc()` returns an `int`, either with the negative value `EOF` indicating end of file or input error, or the value of the byte read from the stream as an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

As per you 2nd problem description you need to use `fgetc` and `fputc`, with that you don't need any buffer.

**Syntax's:**

```
int fputc(int char, FILE *pointer)
int fgetc(FILE *pointer)
```

> `fgetc()` reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an `int`, or `EOF` on end of file or error.

That is why `c` is declared as `int` instead of `char`.

**Example:**

```
static void copy (FILE *input, FILE *output)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF){
        fputc(c, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think an emphasis on why `c` is not a `char` would be helpful for the OP.

Comment: @Mayur I think OP is working with plain ASCII, otherwise there should have be an additional `unicode` tag or description for the same.

Comment: Got it! But I fscanf and fprintf is still not working, could someone please help me with that?

Comment: @Betty Did you consider Xings input in comment section?